# How can I transfer the contents of cells from one Excel file to another automatically?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two Excel files, the first file contains about 5500 cells, the second file is empty and I want to transfer the contents of each sheet in the first file to the cells of the second file.

Clearly, I want to transfer the contents of the cells in the first sheet (J2: O2) to glcm11 in the second file , and the contents of cells in the first sheet (J11:O11) to glcm12, and the contents of cells in the first sheet (J20:O20) to glcm13,and the contents of cells in the first sheet (J29:O29) to glcm14.

Then , I want to transfer the contents of the cells in the second sheet (J2: O2) to glcm21 in the second file, and the contents of cells in the second  sheet (J11:O11) to glcm22 , and so on .
How can I do this automatically without the manual method because the number of sheets in the file is too large . Please help me.

[image: the first sheet of the first file]

[image: the second sheet of the first file]
[the second file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERRxL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

### **Solution 1: Formula**

This method is unorthodox but I had fun writing it.... If I was doing this for myself then I probably would have turned to VBA or Power Query.

Before we start, you need to make sure both files are open and that they can be referenced.  Test this by clicking in an empty cell of the second workbook (destination) and typing `=` then click in any cell of the first workbook (source) and press `Enter`.  Now look in the formula bar where you typed `=`, you should see something like `='[Book1]Sheet1'!$A$1`  If you do not see anything after the `=` then try resizing the two workbooks so they are both displayed on the screen and try again.  If you still only see the `=` then try closing the source workbook and opening it from inside the destination workbook's `File Menu` and try again.  If that still doesn't work then neither solution can help you because they need the workbooks need to recognize each other.

You also need to make sure the worksheets in the source file are match the sample data you provided, meaning they are named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, etc.  If they are not named this way then you need to stand facing the corner for an hour so you can consider what else may have been misrepresented in the example you provided.

We're almost ready to start, so go ahead and maximize the destination file window because we're going to do all our work in there; but do not close the source, it needs to remain open.

We begin by typing the name of the source workbook in cell `I1` of the destination.  Do not use any special characters. If the test you did looks like `='[Book1]Sheet1'!$A$1` then you only type `Book1` into cell `I1`.  Remember, this is all inside the destination sheet.

Now copy each of the following three formulas and paste them in the destination sheet.

Copy `="'["&$I$1&"]Sheet0'!"` and paste into `H1`

Copy `=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($D$2),4)=0,LEFT($H$1,FIND("0",$H$1)-1)&VALUE(MID(H1,FIND("0",$H$1),FIND("!",H1)-1-FIND("0",$H$1)))+1&"'!J2",LEFT(H1,FIND("J",H1))&VALUE(MID(H1,FIND("J",H1)+1,LEN(H1)))+9)` and paste into `H2`

Copy `=OFFSET(INDIRECT($H2),0,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2),1,1)` and paste into `B2`

If you did everything right, cell `B2` will have data from cell `J2` in your source sheet and you can use `B2` to populate the range `B2:G2`.  Do this by dragging or copying and pasting, either works.

At this point, `Row 2` should be populated from `B:H` and you should see data from the source file in `B:G` and you can copy `B2:H2` down the sheet as far as you need to go.

When you are satisfied with the results, you can copy your data range and paste over it using `Paste Special Values`.  This will keep the data but break the links to the source file so you can safely remove `Column H`.

---

### **Solution 2: VBA**

I made this more complicated than it really needs to be but it is still easy to follow and use.

1. Begin by closing all of your workbooks and completely closing out of
   Excel.
2. Now create a new workbook then save it with a recognizable name.
3. Open the VBA editor from inside this workbook by pressing `Alt F11`.
4. Activate the project explorer from inside the VBA editor by pressing
   `Ctrl R`.  It is probably on the left side of your screen.
5. Locate your workbook's VBAProject in the project explorer.
6. Right click on your workbook's VBAProject in the project explorer.
7. Expand the `Insert` menu and select `Module`
8. Find `Module1` under your workbook's project in the `Modules`
   folder.
9. Double left click `Module1`
10. Left click inside the large white area in the center of the VBA
     editor and confirm the window title ends with `[Module1(Code)]`
11. Copy the code below and paste it inside the editor.
12. Close the VBA editor and go back to Excel.
13. I recommend saving the workbook as a macro enabled workbook before
     continuing.
14. Left click the `View` tab on the Excel ribbon.
15. Left click the `Macro` icon -or- left click the `Macro` drop down
     menu and select `View Macros` NOTE: your security settings
     determine what happens next.
16. If your security settings allow macros then select
     `CopyDataFromWorkbook` and left click `Run`

If your security settings prevent you from running any macros, you can try change them yourself by opening the `File` menu in Excel, selecting `Options`, `Trust Center`, clicking the `Trust Center Settings` button, selecting `Macro Settings` in the left panel and setting the appropriate level. As a rule, I do not recommend enabling all macros and my personal preference is to only run signed macros but getting you setup for that is beyond the scope of this post.

We just installed the macro in a workbook that is unrelated to your source and destination files to protect your data from any possible error.  I made it flexible enough so that you can install it directly in the source or the destination if you choose.

**What to expect when running the macro**

The macro asks if the source sheet is open.

If you select yes, it lists every workbook that it can see and asks you to select the source. `Not Listed` option was included because it is possible for the source to be open but not visible if it is in a different Excel instance (same problem with the formula above)

If you select no, a window opens and allows you to select the source workbook.

The macro then asks if the destination sheet is open and you follow the same steps.  If you selected the source from a list of open workbooks then that workbook will not be listed for you to select as the destination.

From there it loops through every sheet in the source writing to the destination one row at a time.  I can speed it up a bit if you find it works too slow but I think your data set is small enough that you will not really notice.

**Copty this code and paste it into `Module1` of your VBA project**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDataFromWorkbook()
    Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim dstWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim srcWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim dstWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim srcActiveRow As Long
    Dim dstActiveRow As Long
    Dim arydata()
    Set srcWorkbook = GetAppropriateWorkbook("source file")
    If Not srcWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set dstWorkbook = GetAppropriateWorkbook("destination file", srcWorkbook)
    If Not dstWorkbook Is Nothing Then
         dstActiveRow = 2
        dstWorkbook.Activate
        Set dstWorksheet = dstWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        For Each srcWorksheet In srcWorkbook.Worksheets
            For srcActiveRow = 2 To 29 Step 9
                arydata = srcWorksheet.Range("J" & srcActiveRow, "O" & srcActiveRow)
                dstWorksheet.Range("B" & dstActiveRow, "G" & dstActiveRow) = arydata
                dstActiveRow = dstActiveRow + 1
            Next srcActiveRow
        Next srcWorksheet
        dstWorkbook.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetAppropriateWorkbook(ByVal strRole As String, Optional SelectedWorkbook As Workbook) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    If MsgBox("Is the " & strRole & " open?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "FINDING " & UCase(strRole)) = vbYes Then
        Set ws = ListOpenWorkbooks(SelectedWorkbook)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the " & strRole & " and click 'OK'", Title:="ACTIVATE " & UCase(strRole), Type:=8)
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks(rng.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not detect the " & strRole & ".  Trying a different way."
        End If
    End If
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            .Filters.Clear
            .Title = "Find and open the " & strRole
            .Filters.Add UCase(Space(2) & strRole & Space(40)), "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Show
            If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Mid(.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(.SelectedItems(1), "\") + 1, Len(.SelectedItems(1))))
                ThisWorkbook.Activate
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot continue without a " & strRole, vbCritical, "No " & strRole & " selected"
    Else
        Set GetAppropriateWorkbook = wb
    End If
End Function

Private Function ListOpenWorkbooks(Optional SelectedWorkbook As Workbook) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long
    If Not SelectedWorkbook Is Nothing Then s = SelectedWorkbook.Name
    i = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If s <> wb.Name Then
                ws.Cells(i, 1) = wb.Name
                i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Not listed"
    Set ListOpenWorkbooks = ws
End Function
```

Comment: I tried to apply the above steps but I did not get the correct result, can you contact me and get access to my computer via teamviewer

Comment: No thank you, I will continue to help you here; but it would be good if you at least tried to explain why the result is not correct.  Imagine if you wrote an Excel formula down on a piece of paper and mailed it to a colleague.  And a few days later you get response with "did not get the correct result", how do you help your colleague?  I tested the solution on two computers: Win10 32bit Office 2013 Standard and Win10 64bit Office 365 ProPlus, it works and I cannot help you with the formula if you do not describe how your result differs from the expectation.

Comment: How to apply this code , can you help me ?

Comment: What did you not understand about "Copy and paste into a module and run CopyDataFromWorkbook"?  I cannot help you if you do not explain what it is you do not understand.  I rewrote everything into small steps, maybe that will help, but I cannot learn how to follow them for you.  Learning is something you have to do yourself.

Comment: I have applied the above code , but i did not get the required data format in Excel file

Comment: I have applied the above code , but i did not get the required data format in Excel file . The code transfer only first value (value in "J" cell ) from the source file ,and copied it to all excel cells in the destination file (from B to G)

Comment: Great, that means you're doing it right!  There was a minor error in my code.  I used `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose` when I didn't need to.  I've corrected the code and tested.  It will work for your now.

Comment: thank you ,please the code back to me in the corrected format

Comment: @AhmadSarairah I updated the code 2 days ago.

Comment: @AhmadSarairah I updated the code 2 days ago.